# Should I edit the question, or delete it and repost the question?

Tags: discussion, editing, deletion

> I am speaking on reference to this question :- [In $\Delta ABC,$ side $AC$ and the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ meet at $D$, where $BD$ bisects $\angle ABC$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906150/in-delta-abc-side-ac-and-the-perpendicular-bisector-of-bc-meet-at-d-w)

The Problem is that others had discussed and said that this question is unsolvable , and the above fact is true for infinitely many triangles. I realised that is true, because I missed to give a small information that $AD = 9$ as well.

It also got answered by an user who took effort to answer it.

So what should I do in this case, edit the question or delete and repost it?

The fact that small information which I missed, if I apply that in the question, I am already getting my answer myself. So actually there was no need for me to post this question. But what should I do in this case?

**Related Questions** 
:- [Should I delete and repost my question to regenerate interest?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/should-i-delete-and-repost-my-question-to-regenerate-interest) 
:- [Edit a question significantly or reposting it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28031/edit-a-question-significantly-or-reposting-it)

Comment: You cannot delete a question with two or more answers, or with one answer that has a positive score.

Comment: Yes, but what I did is edited it along with accepting the answer which the user has given, as well as mentioning my mistake and solving it as my own answer.

Comment: But you cannot delete a question with an answer that has a positive score. So you cannot delete your question.

Comment: You are right, but when the answer had no votes I could have deleted it, so the only option which is left right now was to edit it, and that's what I did.

Comment: Be careful that your edit does not nullify answers formerly correct.  I would suggest you not edit *your question* for this reason; the answerers answered in good faith. And since you yourself can now solve the problem, please do not repost. Perhaps you can post an answer, explaining that you left out a premise, and they proceed to answer the question with that premise, in an *answer* field.

Comment: Do **not** edit a question to change its meaning after someone has answered it.  If you realize that your question was in error, but it has an answer, ask a new question.  Regarding what to do with the old question, you could delete it (if the answer is not upvoted, or if there is only one answer)---I would suggest that if you do this, you leave a comment first, explaining why you are deleting the question.  It is considered rude to delete a question after it has been answered.  You could also choose to simply leave it up.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I cannot delete the question as it got upvoted, and also leaving it like that feels bad as there was some mistake which I had made. So what I did is left the question as it is, and left an answer as my mistake which I made as well as explaining the answer to the question, like amWhy said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your first question already has an answer, leave it as is and ask a new one.   The first question, even though it's not what you intended, already became a piece of knowledge in Q&A style. Maybe it can benefit others. Maybe not, but there's no need to delete it.

In your new question, you should link to the first one as context.

Note: in your specific case, however, it seems you also figured out the answer to your intended question. In this case, no need to create a new question. Just do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I would believe that it would be easier to edit than delete, because if you post a lot of questions that are badly received, then you can't post for a while. And no: don't repost a question you already asked. It will most likely be shut down because they are highly downvoted.